# Flutter for each loop doesn't wait the result of the other firebase reading

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code

```
data.forEach((index, data) async { 
                 
 String id=data['LampId'];
 print(id);
var _firebaseRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('lamps').child(id);

     await  _firebaseRef2.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) async {
           print(snapshot.value["Owner"]);
                              
                 if(snapshot.value["Owner"]==Data.userid){
                       item.add({"key": index, ...data});
                    }else{
                        print("no");
                           }
});
                  
                 
                            
                      
                  });


return ListView.builder (
                        
                        itemCount: item.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Display Cards
```

i want to check if the id is of the owner and then add to the list but it happens that the foreach ids are printed 1st then it goes to the other firebase check

If i explain more precisely this is the result that is printed

```
I/flutter (15436): lamp002
I/flutter (15436): lamp003
I/flutter (15436): lamp001
I/flutter (15436): 001
I/flutter (15436): 002
I/flutter (15436): no
I/flutter (15436): 001
```

as you can see all the lap ids are printed 1st so it misses the checking of the userid and and addling to the list.

In other words when item add is in the if condition it do not add anything while if i put it outside the firebaseRef2 it is adding all the lamp list

Answer (score 0):

Use await to tell flutter to wait:

```
await _firebaseRef2.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) async
```

Comment: I have tried it actually id adds to the list but i have used return ListView.builder at that point i think it is passed before the list is added